# 'packed like sardines' vs. 'chock-a-block'

Tags: meaning, expressions, differences

> The fans were packed like sardines at the music festival.
>
> The fans were chock-a-block at the music festival.

Are there differences in meaning between that two sentences? In a equal space, does 'packed like sardines' imply more or less people than 'chock-a-block'?

Comment: You'd tend to say the music festival was chock-a-block, not the fans themselves.

Comment: @Urbycoz In what dialect is *?chock-a-block* alleged to occur?

Comment: It's pretty common in British English. In fact, I seem to remember a favourite program of mine from my childhood with that name...http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CGYQtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DjnWcm5dr45s&ei=fDk2UMynPIjX0QWplIGYDQ&usg=AFQjCNGA_cKjfoBACkhg5Cyq7vuyheFLgA

Comment: Great comparison question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with Urbycoz for British English; I believe your phrasing is used in American English. To my British ear, "chock-a-block" is a lower register than "packed like sardines" — I definitely prefer your first option.

Comment: I see *[chockablock](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chockablock#Adjective)* as a perfectly fine word, certainly not as down-market as “packed like sardines”.

Comment: I think there must be a AmE/BrE difference. 'chockablock' sounds to me (AmE), instead of downmarket, just old-fashioned and maybe even a tiny bit more formal